# How to modularize a delete route with params in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters, routes

I am trying to hit a delete route in my Express.js app, and it is not working for some reason.

There is some issue with the way that I am setting up my router files and the request params in the listener.

I've tried all sorts of variations, and can't see what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for any pointers!

the url in the request from the client is:

**DELETE: "localhost:8080/api/tasks/1"**

the structure of the route modules is like this:

1. catch all of the urls that start with "/api" in the *app.js* file and send them to *routes/index.js*
2. in routes/index, send all of the urls that start with "api/tasks" to *routes/tasks.js*
3. in routes/task.js send all of the requests that have a delete verb */routes/tasks/delete.js*

in routes/tasks/delete.js, there is a route:

```
router.delete("/:id, async (req, res, next)=>{
     ISSUE -----> this route never gets hit
})
```

**More details:**
***the route files are like this:***

**/app.js**

```
app.use("/api", require("./routes/index.js"));
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;


/**
 * @route /api/tasks
 * @verb get
 */
router.use("/tasks", require("./tasks"));
```

**/routes/tasks/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;

/**
 * @route /api/tasks
 * @verb post
 */
router.post("/", require("./create"));

/**
 * @route /api/tasks
 * @verb get
 */

router.get("/", require("./read"));

/**
 * @route /api/tasks
 * @verb put
 */

router.put("/", require("./update"));

/**
 * @route /api/tasks
 * @verb delete
 */

router.delete("/", require("./delete"));
```

**/routes/tasks/delete.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../../models/db");
const { User, Task } = db.models;

module.exports = router;


router.delete("/:id", async (req, res, next) => {

  let { id } = req.params;


  // ISSUE: THIS ROUTE DOES NOT GET HIT

  console.log("hit delete route");

  try {

    res.json({ test, "hit the delete route", id });

  } catch (error) {

    next(error);

  }
});

/**
```

Comment: Do any of the other methods work for the tasks router?

Comment: i believe its because you are exporting too early, use `module.exports` at the end of the file

Comment: @about14sheep yes, the create, read, and update routes work; but they don't have url params. I will try them with a param too and update the question.

Comment: @alilland Thank for the pointer. I just tried to move all the "module.exports = router" statements to the end of the files; and it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two conflicts

1. `app.use(...)` is for loading an exported router
2. the way you are loading individual routes is incorrect, they will not load in an exported route, they will instead take in a function (also called a "controller" in many frameworks)

```js
// file 1 ./deleteController.js
const deleteController = (req, res, next) => {
  // ...
}

module.exports = deleteController
```

```js
// file 2 ./deleteRoutes.js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const deleteController = require('./deleteController')

router.delete('/:id', deleteController)

module.exports = router
```

```js
// file 3 ./index.js
// ...

app.use("/someNamespace", require("./deleteRoutes"))

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, @alilland. Changing the router.delete("/", require("./delete")) to router.use("/delete", require("./delete")) and then changing my url to "/api/tasks/delete/1" - fixed it.  I'll refactor the controllers and routers, so that the url can be DELETE."/api/tasks/1" in the future.